# Android external sdCard DCIM folder path

Tags: android, path, android-sdcard

I need the DCIM folder path from the external sdCard if it is present.
I have observed that this path changes according to the manufacturer of the device `("/storage/extSdCard", "/storage/SdCard", "mnt/storage/extSdCard", ...)`

Is there any Android api that would give me the path irrespective of the device?

Answer (score 3):

Try out with

```
String m_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();
```

For the more details about the storage file structure you check my [Blog](http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2014/01/android-storage-system-to-access-path.html)

Comment: I have tried  `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();` But this give me the path of the internal storage DCIM folder.

Comment: Its giving path of external storage only. Have you tried to print the path ? @MayurMore

Comment: @GrIsHu you didn't understand. Author meant MicroSD card:  https://cdn1-shop.mikroe.com/img/product/microsd-16gb/microsd-16gb-thickbox_default-1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem using a Samsung device. 
Using the Google Photos App I was able to identify the real location of my SD-Card storage: "/storage/837D-10EB/DCIM" as opposed to the String given by the Environment framework, which is "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM". I don't know if this is a Samsung "problem" or if it has something to do with Android settings. Anyway, it would be good to know if there is an alternative way of finding the SD-Card Camera storage. I know there has to be one as the Google Photos app also finds those photos without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here in the API Guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

The basic steps are:
1. Check the storage state (if it exists)
2. Get the storage Path
3. Go further in a directory you want
4. Make a folder, read a file, write a file, etc. That part is up to you.

This is taken from the docs:

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```