# Path to Android folder with all images

Tags: android, path

I'm trying to build a feature to load the latest saved image from the device into an app.
Currently I'm using this path `DCIM/Camera/` but it only stores camera taken images. Is there a folder that stores all images? (screenshots, images saved from the web or camera roll)

Comment: posibble duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751041/android-external-sdcard-dcim-folder-path

Comment: I don't see a reason to either down-vote this or close it. And @JozeRi your duplicate doesn't really fit either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of searching in in folders for the images, you can let the system take care of that for you.

Android indexes most media-data (images, music, etc) on it's own and offers [Content Providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to query these databases.

For your purposes, you can use the [`MediaStore.Images.Media`-provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html).

```
public List<String> getImagePaths(Context context) {
    // The list of columns we're interested in:
    String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED};

    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().
            query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, // Specify the provider
                    columns, // The columns we're interested in
                    null, // A WHERE-filter query
                    null, // The arguments for the filter-query
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC" // Order the results, newest first
            );

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(cursor.getCount());

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int image_path_col = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        do {
            result.add(cursor.getString(image_path_col));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return result;
}
```

The method will return a list of the image-paths of all images that are currently indexed by the MediaStore with the latest first. You'll need the `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`-permission for this to work!