# Display all images on android device

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to create an application that on one of its activities it displays all the images on the device for the user to chose one of them.

I managed to only display all the images on the DCIM/Camera folder.

This is my code for displaying the images:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
gridview.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));

String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/DCIM/Camera";

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
for (File file : files)
    imageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Can someone help me here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `MediaStore`, rather than trying to work with the filesystem directly.

Comment: why don't you use a picking Intent? And wouldn't using a `Cursor` for this search be much easier?

Comment: to display all avaiable images on android device you have to search through all accessible folders (some may require root access) and its files to determine witch one can be image

Comment: Can you point me to code samples of Media Store or using Cursor or everything else? Thank you

Comment: @ItzickBinder http://stackoverflow.com/a/30426102/717341

Answer (score 0):

On click (maybe upload button) :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

When user has selected an image :

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.inSampleSize = 8;
            final InputStream ist;
            try {
                ist = mActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ist, null, options);
                mPicturePath = compressImage(bitmap).getAbsolutePath();
                //recycling bitMap to overcome OutOfMemoryError
                if(bitmap!=null){
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    bitmap=null;
                }
                ist.close();

            //you have mPicturePath do something with it!
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                logoUploadFaied();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logoUploadFaied();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
           //Not uploading
        }
    }
```

Here is Compress Image code, it takes in a bitmap as argument, stores it locally (compressed) and returns file path. Excellent if you want to upload your images to server like whatsapp:

```
 public File compressImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        int actualHeight = bmp.getHeight();
        int actualWidth = bmp.getWidth();

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = logoMaxWidth / logoMaxHeight;
//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image
        if (actualHeight > logoMaxHeight || actualWidth > logoMaxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = logoMaxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) logoMaxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = logoMaxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) logoMaxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) logoMaxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) logoMaxWidth;
            }
        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, actualWidth, actualHeight, true);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            logoUploadFaied();
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        String uriSting = (System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + uriSting);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logoUploadFaied();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            logoUploadFaied();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.write(getBytesFromBitmap(scaledBitmap));
            fos.close();
            //recycling bitMap to overcome OutOfMemoryError
            if(scaledBitmap!=null){
                scaledBitmap.recycle();
                scaledBitmap=null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logoUploadFaied();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
```