# How to use FileObserver?

Tags: java, android

There is a very popular class over the internet, `RecursiveFileObserver` , which can be used to detect any read/write changes made on the file system, recursively, this class can be found [here](https://github.com/dlech/owncloud-android/blob/master/src/com/owncloud/android/utils/RecursiveFileObserver.java), [here](https://github.com/cyphre-llc/cyphre-android/blob/master/src/com/owncloud/android/utils/RecursiveFileObserver.java), and also [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Example/course/com_toraleap_collimator_utilRecursiveFileObserver_java.htm). But the problem is how do I use this calss? I copied it to my project and it does not do anything. How do I start it?
I am a beginner.

```
package com.toraleap.collimator.util;
//from   w  w w .j  a  v  a  2s.c  o  m
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Enhanced FileObserver to support recursive directory monitoring basically.
 * @author    uestc.Mobius <mobius@toraleap.com>
 * @version  2011.0121
 */
public class RecursiveFileObserver extends FileObserver {
    /** Only modification events */
    public static int CHANGES_ONLY = CREATE | DELETE | CLOSE_WRITE | MOVE_SELF | MOVED_FROM | MOVED_TO;

    List<SingleFileObserver> mObservers;
    String mPath;
    int mMask;

    public RecursiveFileObserver(String path) {
        this(path, ALL_EVENTS);
    }

    public RecursiveFileObserver(String path, int mask) {
        super(path, mask);
        mPath = path;
        mMask = mask;
    }

    @Override
    public void startWatching() {
        if (mObservers != null) return;

        mObservers = new ArrayList<SingleFileObserver>();
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        stack.push(mPath);

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            String parent = stack.pop();
            mObservers.add(new SingleFileObserver(parent, mMask));
            File path = new File(parent);
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            if (null == files) continue;
            for (File f : files)
            {
                if (f.isDirectory() && !f.getName().equals(".") && !f.getName().equals("..")) {
                    stack.push(f.getPath());
                }
            }
        }

        for (SingleFileObserver sfo : mObservers) {
            sfo.startWatching();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stopWatching() {
        if (mObservers == null) return;

        for (SingleFileObserver sfo : mObservers) {
            sfo.stopWatching();
        }
        mObservers.clear();
        mObservers = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
        switch (event)
        {
            case FileObserver.ACCESS:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "ACCESS: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.ATTRIB:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "ATTRIB: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "CLOSE_NOWRITE: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "CLOSE_WRITE: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.CREATE:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "CREATE: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.DELETE:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "DELETE: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.DELETE_SELF:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "DELETE_SELF: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.MODIFY:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MODIFY: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.MOVE_SELF:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MOVE_SELF: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.MOVED_FROM:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MOVED_FROM: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.MOVED_TO:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MOVED_TO: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.OPEN:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "OPEN: " + path);
                break;
            default:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "DEFAULT(" + event + "): " + path);
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Monitor single directory and dispatch all events to its parent, with full path.
     * @author    uestc.Mobius <mobius@toraleap.com>
     * @version  2011.0121
     */
    class SingleFileObserver extends FileObserver {
        String mPath;

        public SingleFileObserver(String path) {
            this(path, ALL_EVENTS);
            mPath = path;
        }

        public SingleFileObserver(String path, int mask) {
            super(path, mask);
            mPath = path;
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            String newPath = mPath + "/" + path;
            RecursiveFileObserver.this.onEvent(event, newPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made few changes to `RecursiveFileObserver`:

- Adds member variable `activity`. `activity` is passed in to constructor. It is then used to output `Toast` message when file is created or modified.
- In `onEvent()` Switch case, `Toast` message is shown whenever new file is created, or existing file is modified.

You may follow these steps to setup the file observer:

1) If you already have a project in Android Studio, add a new java file in the same folder / directory as your `MainActivity.java` file. Name the new class as `RecursiveFileObserver`. Copy & paste the below content into your `RecursiveFileObserver.java` file.

Note the first line is `package com.example.shuwnyuan.barchart;`. **You have to replace it with your own package name**, get your package name from first line of your `MainActivity.java` file.

```
// replace this below 1 line with your own package name.
package com.example.shuwnyuan.barchart;

//from   w  w w .j  a  v  a  2s.c  o  m
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Enhanced FileObserver to support recursive directory monitoring basically.
 * @author    uestc.Mobius <mobius@toraleap.com>
 * @version  2011.0121
 */
public class RecursiveFileObserver extends FileObserver {
    /** Only modification events */
    public static int CHANGES_ONLY = CREATE | DELETE | CLOSE_WRITE | MOVE_SELF | MOVED_FROM | MOVED_TO;

    List<SingleFileObserver> mObservers;
    String mPath;
    int mMask;
    Activity activity;

    public RecursiveFileObserver(String path, Activity activity) {
        super(path, ALL_EVENTS);
        mPath = path;
        mMask = ALL_EVENTS;

        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public RecursiveFileObserver(String path, int mask, Activity activity) {
        super(path, mask);
        mPath = path;
        mMask = mask;

        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void startWatching() {
        if (mObservers != null) return;

        mObservers = new ArrayList<SingleFileObserver>();
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        stack.push(mPath);

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            String parent = stack.pop();
            mObservers.add(new SingleFileObserver(parent, mMask));
            File path = new File(parent);
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            if (null == files) continue;

            for (File f : files)
            {
                if (f.isDirectory() && !f.getName().equals(".") && !f.getName().equals("..")) {
                    stack.push(f.getPath());
                }
            }
        }

        for (SingleFileObserver sfo : mObservers) {
            sfo.startWatching();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stopWatching() {
        if (mObservers == null) return;

        for (SingleFileObserver sfo : mObservers) {
            sfo.stopWatching();
        }
        mObservers.clear();
        mObservers = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, final String path) {
        switch (event)
        {
            case FileObserver.ACCESS:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "ACCESS: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.ATTRIB:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "ATTRIB: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "CLOSE_NOWRITE: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "CLOSE_WRITE: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.CREATE:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "CREATE: " + path);

                // show Toast message
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "File created: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                break;
            case FileObserver.DELETE:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "DELETE: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.DELETE_SELF:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "DELETE_SELF: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.MODIFY:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MODIFY: " + path);

                // show Toast message
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "File modified: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                break;
            case FileObserver.MOVE_SELF:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MOVE_SELF: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.MOVED_FROM:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MOVED_FROM: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.MOVED_TO:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "MOVED_TO: " + path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.OPEN:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "OPEN: " + path);
                break;
            default:
                Log.i("RecursiveFileObserver", "DEFAULT(" + event + "): " + path);
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Monitor single directory and dispatch all events to its parent, with full path.
     * @author    uestc.Mobius <mobius@toraleap.com>
     * @version  2011.0121
     */
    class SingleFileObserver extends FileObserver {
        String mPath;

        public SingleFileObserver(String path) {
            this(path, ALL_EVENTS);
            mPath = path;
        }

        public SingleFileObserver(String path, int mask) {
            super(path, mask);
            mPath = path;
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            String newPath = mPath + "/" + path;
            RecursiveFileObserver.this.onEvent(event, newPath);
        }
    }
}
```

2) We will watch for file changes in Android `ExternalStorageDirectory`. In order to do that, we need to explicitly ask user to grant the file read / write permission. We do this in `onCreate` of `MainActivity`. After permission is granted, we watch path for file changes. Then we write to a file called "MyTestFile" to test the `RecursiveFileObserver`. Upon first time of writing, new file is created. After that, the same file is modified if already exist. `Toast` message will be shown when file is created or modified.

In your `MainActivity` class, made this changes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .....

        if (Settings.System.canWrite(this) == false) {
            // for first time, request user to grant file permission
            requestPermissions(new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                }, 3000
            );

        } else {
            // permission is already granted
            // start watching path & write to file for test
            watchPathAndWriteFile();
        }
    }

    .....
    ......

    // This function does 2 things:
    // 1) watch path for files changes using "RecursiveFileObserver"
    // 2) write to a file for testing
    public void watchPathAndWriteFile() {
        // the following path depends on your Android device. On my system, it is: "/storage/emulated/0/"
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
        RecursiveFileObserver observer = new RecursiveFileObserver(path, this);

        // start watching the path
        observer.startWatching();

        // if file "MyTestFile" not exist, new file is created. Else file is modified
        try {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "MyTestFile"));
            out.write("my file content for test...");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            android.util.Log.e("writeStringAsFile", "Exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    // in "onCreate", user is prompted to grant file read / write permission
    // this function is invoked automatically after user allowed / denied permission
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 3000: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // user granted permission
                    // start watching for path & write to file for testing.
                    watchPathAndWriteFile();
                } else {
                    // user denied permission
                    android.util.Log.e("Permission", "Denied");
                }

                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your question, you mentioned you copied the source code of `RecursiveFileObserver` into your project, which you show as in `package com.toraleap.collimator.util`. There is `onEvent()` funtion there, you need to  implement what you want inside that `onEvent` function. Don't just copy that `onEvent` function to your `MainActivity`. What is your `MainActivity` package name look like? You can rename the `package com.toraleap.collimator.util` accordingly.

Comment: For `RecursiveFileObserver` that you copied, it extends `FileObserver`. `onEvent` is a method from the parent class `FileObserver`. `RecursiveFileObserver` overrides `onEvent` method of it's parent. So simply move `onEvent` to other class (eg: MainActivity) it wrong, it doesn't `overrides` anything in your `MainActivity` class.

Comment: I change my answer to explain steps by steps. You should be able to test `RecursiveFileObserver ` by following that. Hope this help, good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I think this code rather creates a file in the specified directory, if not present, I wanted to show a toast when new pictures are taken in the DCIM directory, so how do I listen to that event ? :)

Comment: For `DCIM` path, you can try this: `String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();`. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751041/android-external-sdcard-dcim-folder-path

Comment: I know how to give the path, but I don't see the listener part, which detects changes, where do i show the toast when files are created?

Comment: In the answer, I have made changes to `RecursiveFileObserver` file & posted the complete edited version. It is already showing `Toast` when file is created / modified. In `onEvent` -> `case FileObserver.CREATE:`, code that show `Toast` is `Toast.makeText(activity, "File created: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. You just need to copy my version of `RecursiveFileObserver` into your project. To use it, it is just something like `RecursiveFileObserver observer = new RecursiveFileObserver(path, this);  observer.startWatching();`. I show inside my answer -> `watchPathAndWriteFile()`.

Comment: if a new file is added, which event will be called? is it still working?