# How to access files saved programatically in Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM in Windows Operating system?

Tags: android

My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751041/android-external-sdcard-dcim-folder-path) since I do not use a SD Card.

I take a picture using Camera API and here is how I save the file :

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

This works fine. When I browse in my phone native camera app or even in the phones documents, I see the files (i.e. the pictures).

**Problem : ** When the phone is connected to my laptop (Windows 10) using USB (whatever protocol is used here i.e MTP, PTP, USB), when I browse to the DCIM folder, I dont see the files. I though it was hidden, I tried to unhide it, but still it does not show.

Can you help me find this file so that I can copy it to my laptop for testing purposes ?

Comment: Is your phone detected on Android Studio ?

Comment: @113408 Yes it is

Comment: Would you mind showing the result of `pictureFile.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: @113408  Here it is : `/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/Picture_20192826102834.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Android Studio`'s File Explorer pane to access files in your phone/emulator
[image: AS File explorer]

From your comment it seems that you store your pictures on the SDCard so you might access them from :
[image: DCIM]

Comment: Try to use adb like this : `adb pull /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/Picture_20192826102834.jpg C:\Users\YOUR_USER\Desktop`

Comment: Awesome. `adb pull` did the job. Thanks you. Can I have a little more explanation why we need to do that to get the file ?

Comment: @tomjohnes  normally you would access the DCIM folder by plugging your phone normally into usb and going to the said directory. The best utility IMO to do that is AS file explorer but since it kept loading for you (not sure why) we just switched to more radical way which is adb pull